# How to Send Email using office 365 exchange online in C#?

Tags: c#-4.0

I have seen many examples related to sending mails via office 365 SMTP but cant find any help for 
office 365 exchange online using c#.
It would be great some one can help me in this with an example so that I can understand the difference between these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn567668(v=exchg.150).aspx

This helped me, it has got proper reference for all the queries you might have.